# WS-Security: HttpsToken could not be asserted

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ws-security

I've got following ws policy inside my WSDL :

```
    <wsp:Policy wssutil:Id="Wssp1.2-2007-Https-UsernameToken-Plain.xml">
    <ns1:TransportBinding xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
        <wsp:Policy>
            <ns1:TransportToken>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <ns1:HttpsToken/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </ns1:TransportToken>
            <ns1:AlgorithmSuite>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <ns1:Basic256/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </ns1:AlgorithmSuite>
            <ns1:Layout>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <ns1:Lax/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </ns1:Layout>
            <ns1:IncludeTimestamp/>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </ns1:TransportBinding>
    <ns2:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
        <wsp:Policy>
            <ns2:UsernameToken
                ns2:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <ns2:WssUsernameToken10/>
                    <ns2:HashPassword/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </ns2:UsernameToken>
        </wsp:Policy>
    </ns2:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:Policy>
```

To supporut WS security inside my client I've implemented:

```
        ((BindingProvider) port ).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, this.URL);

        AddressingProperties maps = new AddressingPropertiesImpl();
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.addressing.context", maps);

        Map<String, Object> ctx = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();

        ctx.put("ws-security.callback-handler", UsernamePasswordCallback.class.getName());

        UsernamePasswordCallback.user = this.USER;
        UsernamePasswordCallback.pass = this.PASS;

        ctx.put("ws-security.username", UsernamePasswordCallback.user);
        ctx.put("ws-security.callback-handler", UsernamePasswordCallback.class.getName());

        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
        client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
```

As far as I understand, that's how you usually do it when you have `WssUsernameToken10` and `HashPassword`. The problems seems to be with TransportBinding:

```
HttpsToken could not be asserted: HttpURLConnection is not a HttpsURLConnection
```

Some people have faced this problem in the past, unfortunately, there seems to be no solution, no single reply.

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah - sorry, forgot to post an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone faces similar issue I recommend to look at cxf library version: different versions on the server side and the client side might be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<ns1:HttpsToken/>` with http:// url (for example you are in development environment not using https) you will most likely have en error message complaining about HttpsToken issue with Http connection
If you are using HTTP connection replace HttpsToken to HttpToken.